# Multiple types of a class within a class

Tags: kotlin, oop

I'm making a simple game to learn some kotlin, and I'm a little confused on the best way to change this around using OOP.

I have a class for backpack setup so that it has another class called items that will be different types of items. Below I've recreated a simple version of what I have.

```
class backPack {
      private val item: Item

init { item = Item() }

     fun display() {
     item.display()
     }
}

class Item {
      fun display() { println("Your item!") }
}

fun main() {
 val examplePack = backPack()
 examplePack.display()
}
```

I want to change the backPack class to allow for different types of items. For example, health potions and mana potions. I considered making the item an open class, then having something like this:

```
class healthPotion : Item() {
    override fun display() {
        println("health potion!")
    }
}
class manaPotion : Item() {
    override fun display() {
        println("mana potion!")
    }
}
```

which seems correct, but I'm a little stuck on how to refactor the backpack class to allow different types of items and I want to make sure this seems like a proper way to do this. Any assistance is very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically the idea! If your `BackPack` class (it should start with a capital by convention) handles `Item`s, then any class that has that type will work. You have two options - inheritance, and composition.

Inheritance is where you build a hierarchy of classes, e.g.:

```
open class Item {
    val weight: Int
    fun Describe()
}

open class Potion : Item() {
    fun drink() {}
}

// this is a Potion, and a Potion is an Item, meaning this is an Item
class ManaPotion : Potion() {
    override fun drink() {
       println("whoa!")
    }
}

// etc
```

The problem there is you're locked into a rigid hierarchy - what if you had a `StaleBread` that's a `Food`, but you also want it to be a `Weapon`? You can use *interfaces* to compose your object by giving it multiple types, not just a parent:

```
open class Item

interface Food {
    fun eat() {
        println("yum")
    }
}

interface Weapon {
    fun attack() {
        println("RARGH")
    }
}

class StaleBread : Item(), Food, Weapon
```

Because `StaleBread` has all of those types, you can treat it as *any* of them, because it *is* all of them. Because it's a `Weapon`, it's guaranteed to have an `attack()` method, etc. You can add it to a `List<Food>`, because it `is` a `Food`. Being able to treat objects as different *types* is called *polymorphism*. So you're able to *compose* an object from different types, to give it certain properties, certain behaviours, etc

---

Your example should work as-is because you're handling `Item`s in your backpack, and your two potion classes are both `Item`s (descendants of that class, specifically, since you're inheriting from the `Item` class). There are lots of ways to organise it - if you get into some tutorials about inheritance, composition and polymorphism (this is only a simple overview that skips over a bunch of things) you'll start to get some ideas about how to move forward

---

oh yeah, for the actual backpack, you probably want something like this:

```
class BackPack {
    private val items = mutableListOf<Item>()

    fun addItem(item: Item) {
        // here you could do things like check it doesn't exceed the allowed weight
        // or capacity of the backpack
        items.add(item)
    }
}
```

This way, your backpack can contain multiple `Item`s, and you can control how those are accessed through the class's functions and properties. Anything which is an `Item` type can go in there!

Comment: Your example Item and Potion classes should be marked `open`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I am familiar with polymorphism and inheritance but entirely new with kotlin and was a little confused about the way to do this, but this is really helpful.

I think I might have used a bad example, because what I'm really creating is loot from after a battle, so I want the item to not be a list of items, but for example when the backpack is searched you find either an item that is a health potion, or a mana potion. How would I make item act that way?

Thank you again!

Comment: @williambutcherthe99th oh if you already have a bit of background, it might just help to go over the Kotlin specifics: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html (+interfaces) which build on the Java ones: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java///IandI/index.html

Comment: I was able to figure out my issue, thank you so much for your time and effort, it helped a lot!

Comment: @williambutcherthe99th As far as the loot goes, depends on exactly what you're doing, but you could have `listOf(ManaPotion(), HealthPotion()).random()` which is a `List<Potion>` that you pull a random `Potion` from. (Not the best way to do it, since you're creating instances you end up discarding, but just to keep things simple). To really fit the whole "backpack object" paradigm, when you generate the `BackPack`, you'd `add` the random potion to it, so it's a concrete thing containing a concrete thing. The "what's inside" logic there is in whatever creates the `BackPack`, the loot generator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change which item is in the bag, the property should be a `var`. If you want the bag to be able to be empty, then it should be a nullable property (declared with a `?` after the type so it can hold null).

By the way, class names should always start with a capital letter so your code will be easier to read. And you can initialize properties at the declaration site instead of using a separate `init` block.

```
class Backpack {
    var item: Item? = null

    fun display() {
        item?.display()
    }
}
```

Your generic `Item()` doesn't seem like it would be useful in practice. Therefore, Item should probably be either an `abstract class` or an `interface`. A general OOP principle is that you should avoid deep class hierarchies. If your superclass doesn't contain logic that must be shared by all its children, it should probably be an interface instead.

Comment: Thank you! So, I tried to think up a basic example and it probably doesn't make too much sense in practice because I'm actually doing something a little more complex, the backpack is actually looted items, and I want it to only contain a base item class that says nothing is found, and now I'm adding either the item in the bag is a health potion or a mana potion. 

I'm still a little confused how in main to make a backpack that has a health potion, and a backpack that has a mana potion, if you have any help with that I'd appreciate it so much. Thank you!

Comment: This class can already do that. Just set the `item` property to one of those other class instances. Your idea of making the Item super type represent the non-existence of an Item can be made to work but is very confusing because it breaks the semantics of a Potion being a type of Item and the logic of a parent class carrying the functionality that is common with its children. If the super type names Item represents an absence of having an Item, then every Potion is an object that represents not having an item and then overriding that and actually represents an item after all.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thank you again for your help! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: @williambutcherthe99th If you don't want to make your backpack hold a list of items (which can be empty! Or just hold one thing, you're in control of it),  and you only want to represent a single item instead, you might want to make ``item`` a nullable ``Item?``, where *null* represents the absence of an item. Your backpack can handle that representation internally, say if you have a ``describe`` function that says `"Empty backpack"` if ``item`` is null, otherwise it prints ``"Backpack containing ${item.name}"``, that kind of thing